# Using Encrypt & decryption method in load runner

Tags: performance, load-testing, loadrunner

I am creating a script in load runner to test an application that uses encryption & decryption method to encrypt & decrypt the request & response. 
Developer have provided me the method in jar file to encrypt & decrypt request & response.
How could I use these methods in my loadrunner script & in which to put this jar file to use its methods in lr.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Java Virtual User

OR convert the algorithm's to the language of your tool

OR convert the virtual user type you are using to Java (see alternate forms of web virtual user)

OR Package the encryption on a DLL and use lr_load_dll() to register the DLL and to take advantage of the functions included therin

OR Run a GUI Virtual User which will automatically inherit the classes

OR Run a RDP/Citrix virtual user which will automatically inherit the classes